# No ending delimiter '/' found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this regex which matches blood group

```
'bloodgroup' => 'required|regex:/(A|B|AB|O)[-+]/',
```

But when I run this it gives me the error

> No ending delimeter '/' found

how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Since your `regex` has a pipe in it, you have to use an array,

**Use This:**

```
 'bloodgroup' => ['required','regex:/(A|B|AB|O)[-+]/'],
```

Link to the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex).

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex):

> Note: When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

So, since you're using pipes `|`, you need to use an array instead of a string:

```
'bloodgroup' => ['required', 'regex:/(A|B|AB|O)[-+]/'],
```